# Kubernetes Pod/Service Architecture

Tags: kubernetes, web-deployment, scalability, google-kubernetes-engine

I am working on a project using Django on Google Kubernetes Engine and have a few questions on the best architecture format might be. Right now I have several containers in one pod because they are all dependent on each other and communicate frequently. Here is my setup:

Pod: webapp

Containers:

- NGINX (serves static content, sends traffic to django website)
- website (Django, serves http responses)
- DB Proxy (MySQL server for website and websocket server)
- websocket (Django worker to manage websockets)
- redis (asynchronous functionality)

My plan is to create a deployment that runs several replicas and scales, but is it better to break this pod into multiple pods or a leave it as a single pod?

If I were to break it down, what might that architecture look like after adding in the necessary services? I'm new if this doesn't show it lol

Comment: If you want to achieve greater scalability, you should dispatch these workloads to different pods/microservices. And when your app is  converted to microservices, your kubernetes cluster will optimize your workloads in the best possible way, across different hosts. So if you want to achieve greater scalability dispatch your services and workloads. If not, leave it as it is for now, cause it will bring more complexity and maintainability to your project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better for you to break these containers into multiple pods in order to scale without wasting resources. If you were to scale to for example two instances, a second instance of each container would be started. Your containers will most likely not have identical load and therefore it makes sense to only scale on the containers that are under load, hence it makes sense breaking your 1 pod into several pods. It also makes replacing individual components easier.

The following is an example of several pods, each running a single container. The example shows how you can scale the number of pods based on the component that is under load.

[image: Kubernetes example]

Comment: That's perfect, thank you!
Now when scaling and load balancing the same container over mutiple instances, does kubernetes handle the traffic and networking on it's own?

Comment: Yes, if you run some performance test by bombarding the service with requests you will notice that the request will be handled by a different pod independent of whether they are on the same node.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot! Out of curiosity, do you know if the Django channels runworker server will serve requests alright without communicating to the Django webserver? I also posted that question here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49662320/scaling-django-with-channels-and-nginx-on-kubernetes)

Comment: Also, would the services likely be loadbalancers in kubernetes? Trying to connect all the terms and understand the way it works lol, but as in each service would have its own yaml and all?

Comment: I am not familiar with Django, but I am sure you can separate the websocket workers into their own "micro-service"/application. Instead of calling methods directly, they can communicate through http if they require the webserver for example. You do not need to specify load balancer in the yaml (maybe for finer control) and remember that you can specify multiple things in a single yaml file (config maps, services, etc..).